Randomly select points with a minimum distance in a mesh
I select random points in a mesh using a Random Value Node. I mark those points as 'is selected' with a boolean flag using the Store Named Attribute. I want to make sure, that selected points always have a minimum distance to each other. Points that are to close should not be flagged.
A nice bonus feature would be to control the minimum distance by the points location using a Noise Texture Node
Update
I came up with the following solution that is far from perfect but at the moment fits my needs. I create a point grid where the points have the minimum distance. Afterwards I delete some of the points based on random. At the end I flag the nearest points to that gird as 'is selected'.

This solution has some flaws. Therefore I leave the question open to hopefully find a better solution.

Do you really need "mesh points" or could you maybe use "Distribute points on faces" with a "poisson" option? That has a min distance

Why don't you set the random value to integer and max to "domain size => point count - 1"?

I would be happy if you have got a description on how to archive what I have described. Distributing points on faces is not what I need.
